# How do I get Alluxio POSIX to run with version 3 libfuse?

Tags: alluxio, libfuse

The POSIX documentation says that libfuse version 2.9.3 is required. On my EMR 6.2.0 systems, only 2.9.2 is offered.
I have removed the 2.9.2 libfuse and installed the version 3 libfuse. However, Alluxio does not mount fuse as I suppose it is still looking for 2.9.2.
How do I get Alluxio POSIX to run with version 3 libfuse? Or, is there a 2.9.3 libfuse for EMR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libfuse 2.9.2 supposes to be working with Alluxio Fuse. It's not that much different from 2.9.3. we don't support libfuse 3 yet. https://github.com/Alluxio/alluxio/issues/12758 Supporting libfuse 3 is a nice to have, but we haven't got strong enough reasons/priorities to do the upgrade job.